# Pop-up window where parent sent data by POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, popup

here's my question: I have a table with some info in it.
I want to create a pop-up window when i click on one of the cell value (ex: `foo`). This pop-up will generate informations from a SQL request where the value `foo` will be necessary.

To summarize, is there a pop-up window feature where i can send info in it from the parent window?

Just want to mention that i tried some, but i was only able to put static information in it

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would post the data via ajax. Then depending on the response, you can popup the new window with the desired url.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest in your case is to simply open the popup with an URL in which foo is the needed parameter (directly sent to the server) : http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

If you really need the argument to be sent in POST, then you can access, from the child, a javascript variable in the parent window using `window.opener` (after the popup is opened with a constant URL).

Comment: There is a pop-up feature that allowed that?

Comment: It depends of what you call a popup. If it's simply a child window, yes : http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml